# Renaming a MS Teams Converstaional Bot - App Registration Update

Tags: azure, bots

I've created a conversational bot. I made an error in the name when initially creating the bot. I have since renamed the bot in the App Registration within the Azure portal but the initial name is still displaying in the conversation.

Is there a way to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

You could remove the app registration and then re register it with the correct name.

Comment: I don't believe that may fix the issue. If I create a new app registration, that will issue a new app id. I want to pressure using the same app id. I only need to update existing bot's name in the MS Teams app itself.

Comment: Preserve* not pressure